# Configure elasticsearch via environment variables (docker)

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I want to enable CORS; to do so I can add two lines in `elasticsearch.yml`

```
 http.cors.enabled: true
 http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

And it works. Is there way to do the same but without changing `elasticsearch.yml` and only with environment variables?
I thried to set them in similar way. This is how it looks in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
environment:   
  - http.cors.enabled=true
  - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
```

and it doesn't work properly. Although it works somehow because with the envs set CORS stops working even if I add these parameters to both `elasticsearch.yml` and environment.

Comment: why you need it activate it without modifying `elasticsearch.yml` ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein when running in docker, to modify configuration file i need to create a proxy image that has modified config. But when with environment the official image is enough

Comment: AFAIK If elasticsearch itself does not support enabling via environment variables then there is no other way to do it without modified image

Comment: Two things that make me believe that one can configure ES with environment are following. First - example `docker-compose.yml` from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html sets some variables that also could be found in configuration. Second. Adding enviroment vars like I did in my question breaks everything up, so then at least they have some effect but probably syntax is incorrect.

Comment: you are correct! the official docker image allows you to modify the configuration as described: `Setting the env var cluster.name=testcluster will cause Elasticsearch to be invoked with -Ecluster.name=testcluster` So in this case you might check if the running command of your container contains the variables or not

Comment: @Rugnar I was looking for this it works, just you have remove double quotation:  ```- http.cors.allow-origin=*```

Comment: Also, it worth to mention: if you need to run ES older than 5.0, the DockerHub images does not support providing values by environment variable anyway. You have to mount `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` inside.